# Как сделать так, что бы телеграм бот на пайтон отличал пользывателей

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

Столкнулся с такой проблемой: мой телегам бот не отличает новый человек или же нет, поэтому при начислении количества товаров разные пользователи с разных устройств видят увеличении количества товаров у себя, если другой пользователь нажал кнопку ранее. Как сделать, что бы бот отличал пользователей и каждому давал индивидуальный ответ.

Comment: Завести бд и хранить в ней id чатов как ключ и все остальное, что вам нужно

Comment: Благодарю, вероятно так и сделаю